# Web mobile application with offline mode

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

To begin, I'm sorry for my awful english :)

I have a web application that will communicate frequently with a server running a 
webservice offering JSON / XML. The application will send contact details / bills / products, and will have to manage an offline mode.

I thought to use this DOM cache (HTML5). However I must have constantly an updated customer list, bills etc. in offline mode because I can not make a request to the server.

It is therefore necessary to have an xml file on the mobile ... which will be read and modified. Is it possible and not too difficult to manage XML plaintext database with ExtJS (or another framework) on a mobile? (Android)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's far easier to do with HTML5 storage, which you can use directly without the need for Sencha Touch API calls (providing you're on a supported device, iOS Safari supports web storage).

Have a read of [this article from the Sencha blog](http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-html5-family-web-storage).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) - this can be included in your app without a framework.

If you decide to use Sencha Touch you can use localStorage, which allows you to store key/value pairs in the HTML5 Web Storage on the device.

See this tutorial on the [Sencha website](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aTaking_Sencha_Touch_Apps_Offline). You could use localStorage to cache your json feed whilst making static assets available offline with a cache manifest file.